# Coderush %?SysDate()% date format

Tags: delphi, coderush

Can the date format returned by CodeRush sysDate() be changed. It returns mm/dd/yy where as I want dd/mm/yyyy. Using CodeRush for Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

This function uses Delphi's DateToStr function, which relies upon the text in the ShortDateFormat variable. (See http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ShortDateFormat). You could write a CodeRush plug-in and change this variable, or your could change your locale settings for your machine and change the format that way. Hope this helps.

Comment: My short date format is already dd/mm/yyyy. My version of Coderush is 5.03. I guess this function has been changed in a later version.